# Refreshing UI while waiting for another thread to complete

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have one method (saving data) which I would like to run in different thread. The problem is that data is saved very frequently, since saving is triggered by some other actions (not just user action). This in reality means that, if I would start using async / await, I would need to modify at last 100+ methods (that directly or indirectly call this method), which will require heavy testing.

So, if I do

```
// start the busy indicator
IsBusy = true;

// start the task (saving data)
task.Start();

// now I need to stop further code execution, until task completes, but still allow UI to run that wait indicator.
```

how to not continue executing the code, until the task completes, and still allowing UI to run that busy indicator?

Comment: Could you make the code that needs to wait a callback on the task?

Comment: @LordTakkera As I said, the code that needs to wait is spread to like hundred methods. So, it is a lot of work to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a quick workaround to to use [DispatcherFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a continuation.  Something like this:

```
        IsBusy = true;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // save data
        }).ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            // do more work

            IsBusy = false;
        });
```

Comment: No, I can not use the continuation, because the code after the start new method will continue to run, and that code could be any of the 100 calling methods, so to make them all await for this method, will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the `async` and `await` keywords? These are immensely helpful in keeping things asynchronous without the messy code of continuations (compiler does it behind the scenes for you).

If so, I would highly recommend breaking your methods into `Task`-based operations.

For example:

```
async void StartButtonClicked()
{
    startButton.IsEnabled = false;

    await DoSomeWork();

    startButton.IsEnabled = true;
}

Task DoSomeWork()
{
    // Do some long running background task here.
}
```

The magic is the `await` keyword will wait until the `Task` is completed, but **not** block the UI thread. How does it do that? It registers the rest of the method (after the `await` as a continuation of the `Task` for you).

The result is asynchronous code that functions perfectly and still looks clean. Check out [Microsoft's Guide on Async/Await Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: I am able, but as I said, in order to use async / await, I will need to update a lots of methods that are calling this method (like 100 of them). This is a lot of work, and currently I weas looking for faster solution, while later I could upgrade to using async / await.

Comment: And just as a reminder, that async code that you have used is not correct. A method that will call StartButtonClicked() will not await for the StartButtonClick, because StartButtonClick is a void, while it should be a function that returns Task (or Task<result>).